# log4j2 configuration not logging package starting with org to file

Tags: log4j2

I am migrating a project from log4j to log4j2. The project was using a `log4j.properties` file. Since log4j2 does not support properties file, i have been successful in writing a proper xml configuration file I believe... On running the project i noticed that where the errors from packages starting with org would be written to a file are now being written to the console. This never happened in log4j version 1.

Here's the log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, A1

# Logger for all org packages
log4j.logger.org=ERROR, A2
log4j.additivity.org=false
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.File=../webapps/docs/log/app.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender    
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.A2.File=../webapps/docs/log/org.log
log4j.appender.A2.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=100
```

Heres the subsequent log4j2.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/mnt/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>         
        <RollingFile name="RootErrorFile" fileName="${log-path}/app.log"
                        filePattern="${log-path}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="OrgFile" fileName="${log-path}/org.log"
                        filePattern="${log-path}/org-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>           
        <Logger name="org" level="off" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="OrgFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="RootErrorFile"/>          
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The errors output on the tomcat console are of the pattern

```
Mar 05, 2015 5:53:54 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 290 column 27: Attribute "msg" is required and must be specified for element type "validator".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/docs/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml; lineNumber: 290; columnNumber: 27; Attribute "msg" is required and must be specified for element type "validator".
```

Any help in this regard would be great...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your log config doesn't specify a Console appender, so the webapp is either not using your log config, or that log-line is generated from tomcat itself or another app that isn't using your configuration...  Are you getting other logs in the expected files according to this config?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,,,,Yes i am getting the other logs in the expected files as per the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned `off` the record the `org` package. Change this line:

```xml
<Logger name="org" level="off" additivity="false">
```

by the following:

```xml
<Logger name="org" level="error" additivity="false">
```

If you're using Struts 1.x, this uses Apache Commons Logging. So you need a [bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/log4j-jcl/index.html)

Comment: The bridge log4j-jcl.jar did the trick..Yes the project still uses struts 1.x. Thanks